# Anonymous types mismatch LINQ to SQL query?

Tags: linq

```
List<branch_rating> ObjRat = new List<branch_rating>();      
ObjRat=(_Context.branch_rating
.GroupBy(a => a.restaurant_branch_id)
.Select(a => new { rating = a.Sum(b => b.rating), Name = a.Key })
.OrderByDescending(a => a.rating)).ToList();
```

I tried by putting query in `var` variable and then adding in object.

Below picture shows the error.

[image: i want to get data from branch_rating table having four columns.]

I want to get data from branch_rating table having four columns, I also tried by using var and then adding list data one by one in object.

Comment: Please edit and add the code instead of image!

Comment: If you want people to help you, try explaining and providing as much as information possible. What is DOTopRestaurant? Post your classes that you're trying to map to. Your query returns an anonymous object and you are trying to assign that to a strongly typed List.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be better if you make a custom class like DOTopResturant which includes data members branch_rating,branch_id and then make a object of type DOTopResturant , add every item in variable q into that object.

```
List<branch_rating> ObjRat = new List<branch_rating>();
        ObjRat = _Context.branch_rating.ToList();

  var q = (_Context.branch_rating
 .GroupBy(a => a.restaurant_branch_id)
 .Select(a => new { branch_rating = a.Sum(b => b.rating), branch_id = a.Key })
 .OrderByDescending(a => a.branch_rating)).ToList();

        List<DOTopResturant> ObjTopRes = new List<DOTopResturant>();

        foreach (var item in q)
        {
            ObjTopRes.Add(new DOTopResturant() { branch_id = Convert.ToInt32(item.branch_id), branch_rating = Convert.ToInt32(item.branch_rating) });
        }


        return ObjTopRes;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just read and understand what the error describes :

your are trying to convert an anonymous type (with 2 properties Name and Rating) to another object type branch_rating.

You have 2 solutions :

- work with the anonymous type (using var) :

  ```
  var ObjRat=(_Context.branch_rating  
  .GroupBy(a => a.restaurant_branch_id)
  .Select(a => new { Rating = a.Sum(b => b.rating), Name = a.Key })
  .OrderByDescending(a => a.rating))
  .ToList();
  ```

And then, in your code, just access to Rating and Name properties of your list members.

- work with your type defined branch_rating, by using it in your Select, and use the appropriate constructor.

  ```
  List<branch_rating> ObjRat = new List<branch_rating>();      
  ObjRat=(_Context.branch_rating
  .GroupBy(a => a.restaurant_branch_id)
  .Select(a => new branch_rating() { <Your branch_rating properties assignments here> })
  .OrderByDescending(a => a.rating)).ToList();
  ```

If your branch_rating object does not have an empty constructor, call the correct constructor with good arguments in the Select.

Answer (score 0):

Change select (third row in the picture) to:

```
.Select(a => new DOTopRestaurant {rating = a.Sum(b => b.rating), Name = a.Key})
```

Comment: it shows exception 
"The entity or complex type 'lahorefoodsModel.branch_rating' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query".

Comment: @NomanAhmad Your picture says the exception is connected with DOTopPrestarurant.

Comment: public List<DObranch_rating> GetTopResturantRating()
        {
            List<branch_rating> ObjRat = new List<branch_rating>();
            var q = _Context.branch_rating
 .GroupBy(a => a.restaurant_branch_id)
 .Select(a => new branch_rating { rating = a.Sum(b => b.rating), restaurant_branch_id = a.Key })
 .OrderByDescending(a => a.rating).ToList();
         
            return Mapper.Map<List<DObranch_rating>>(ObjRat);
        }
this is my function and showing exception, kindly guide me?

Answer (score 0):

Delete the declaration of ObjRat and use var:

```
var ObjRat=(_Context.branch_rating  
 .GroupBy(a => a.restaurant_branch_id)
 .Select(a => new { rating = a.Sum(b => b.rating), Name = a.Key })
 .OrderByDescending(a => a.rating))
 .ToList();
```

Your list is a list of the [anonymous type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) not of type `branch_rating`.

If you want to convert it to `branch_rating` use another `Select` to create a `new branch_rating(...)` passing the appropriate parameters to the constructor.

PS You should also look at .NET naming conventions.